# Authenticating with LinkChecker

Tags: html, authentication, hyperlink, linkchecker

I want to use  LinkChecker to validate links across my web pages. However I must be authenticated to view most pages I want to test.

How do I authenticate to a website when I am using LinkChecker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options for setting the username and passwords for authentication are set in the linkcheckerrc config file. You can edit that config file by starting LinkChecker and going to the options dialog.

For syntax see the authentication section:

http://wummel.github.com/linkchecker/man5/linkcheckerrc.5.html

Note that I have found I need to restart LinkChecker to get the config file to be read after changing it.