# Authentication with link checker

Tags: linkchecker

I'm trying to use Link Checker 9.3 (the gui version) to check for broken links on my company's SharePoint site. The site uses Active Directory for user authentication. Every test I run I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852353/authenticating-with-linkchecker). Which refers to [the manual](http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/man5/linkcheckerrc.5.html) and also points out that I probably need to restart each time I make a change.

I've read the manual and still don't know how to properly configure the entry in the config file. Can anyone explain it a little bit?

For example my site is at **https://sites.example.org/services/site/** so I'm thinking that in my config file I should have

```
entry=^https?://sites\.example\.org/services/site Rothrock p@sswArd
```

Do I need to escape the forward slashes? Either way it doesn't work, I still get a 401 unauthorized error

We also have some corporate sites that use a redirect to different authentication scheme and I can't figure those out either. For those I enter something like **https://hr.example.org/wps/portal/hr/home/somepage.html** which will get redirected to **https://security.example.org/secure/signIn.html**. On that page I need to enter my username and credential into two input boxes (userid and password) and click submit. And then I'm redirected to my intended location.

In that case with verbose logging I get a valid 200 ok on **https://security.example.org/securepost/setReturnURL.html** no matter whether somepage.html exists or not.

How do I configure this to work with active directory?
How do I configure this to work with the sign-on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
entry=.* <your ID> <your password>
loginurl=https://security.example.org/secure/signIn.html
loginuserfield=userid
loginpasswordfield=password
```

Note that:

a) LinkChecker's currently got [a cookie bug](https://github.com/wummel/linkchecker/issues/436), so this doesn't work; and

b) LinkChecker's got a [debugging bug](https://github.com/wummel/linkchecker/issues/652), so this doesn't work; and

c) this (probably) clobbers your HTTP authentication, if any.

*SIGH*

Comment: I think IT removed it from my machine because I hadn't used it in so long. I'll see about getting it reinstalled and give it go, but that could take weeks. SIGH...

Comment: Well, it doesn't work (see bug reports), so no rush. Another option might be to log in (e.g. with wget), save the cookie, then have LinkChecker use it during its scan. You'll need to use the same User Agent string & IP, but that should be easy enough.